# Creating a loadmore button and display next set of content in same codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

I am trying to create a loadmore button. If clicked it must load next records appended to previous one.
Here is my controller class

```
class Sample  extends CI_Controller{
  function wall($start)
{
$start = $this->input->post('start');

$resultjson = $this->curl->simple_get("http://www.mywebsite.com/api/posts.php?start=$start&count=10");
$resultant_data = json_decode($resultjson,true);
$data['sample'] = $resultant_data;
$this->load->view('posts',$data);
}
}
```

In My view

```
<html>
<head>
<I have some js files such as masonry>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadmore()
{

$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"http://www.server.com/application/index.php/Sample/wall/",

data :"start=10",
//dataType : 'json',

         success: function (data) {

             alert(data);
         }
});
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
. . . . .
. . . . .
<div id="loadmore" style="margin-top:75%;">
<input type="button" value="loadmore" onclick="loadmore()">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sample is class name and wall is method name
The problem is if i directly call **www.mysite.com/application/sample/wall/10** in the url it gives me **next 10 records**.... But i am unable to display next ten records if clicked on the **loadmore** button.
 i.e if i call **www.mysite.com/application/sample/wall** i will be getting 0 to 10 and a loadmore button. When button is clicked it must display **next ten as well as the earlier data.** 
Can anyone please help me

Comment: Keep a variable outside of `loadmore()` function and use that as your start point. Increase that variable once you have a valid set of data returned from the server.

Comment: actually i am able to increase start value but the problem is the data returned from loadmore is showing empty

Comment: Open your browser console(firebug), make sure the ajax request is made, check the response.

Answer (score 4):

load **www.mysite.com/application/sample/wall/0** at first(default), and same as your code.

**or**
add `if($start == ''){$start = 0;}` in your controller.